# Calling next() on a Scanner initialized by a closed stream doesn't throw IllegalStateException

Tags: java.util.scanner, java, system.in

The `Scanner` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) says that when one calls `next()` on a closed stream then these two exceptions may be thrown:

> NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available
>
> IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

Furthermore `hasNext()` may throw this exception:

> IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

Now let's assume that we have this code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("somefile"));
Scanner sc = new Scanner(fis);
// sc.close();
// sc = new Scanner(fis);
// somefile contents: word1 word2 word3
System.out.println(sc.next());
```

This will print `word1` as expected. If we uncomment `sc.close(); sc = new Scanner(fis);` a `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown when `sc.next()` will be executed.

This behaviour seems strange to me. Shouldn't `hasNext()` and `next()` throw an `IllegalStateException` as the `InputStream` is closed? Please, explain why this is happening.

Comment: As @Andreas said, in my case it threw IllegalStateException: Scanner closed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. `sc.hasNext()` does through a scanner closed exception in that code, it doesn't return false.

Comment: You are right, I got confused. I will update my question a bit later.

Comment: I can't edit my comment anymore and I am truly embarrassed that I screwed this up, but *throw

Comment: OK, I have totaly misunderstood the conditions of my problem. So, I have updated the question which is as it seems very different from the original. Thank you for your time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have misinterpreted `Scanner`’s documentation. It says `next()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if no more tokens are available; this is the case when the underlying stream is either at its end or has been closed. It will only throw an `IllegalStateException` if *the scanner itself* was closed—which does not happen in your question.

Comment: I see. It is a subtle difference but I get it now. Thanks.